# Injuries in Dragon Age 2

Tags: dragon-age-2

I'm playing on hard on a 1.02 patched game and I noticed my characters randomly get injuries. They aren't dying, but somehow over time they get injuries.

Is it something related to the difficulty? Or a bug? It's not game-breaking since I have injury kits to spare, it's just puzzling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Injuries occur either through:

- combat if a character gets **knocked out** source: [DragonAge Wiki](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Injury)
- or from **injured via traps**  source: [Traps](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/988968-dragon-age-ii/58376197/647494469) (no longer true as of [1.03](http://social.bioware.com/page/da2-patches), probably for this reason)

Comment: -1, I specifically mentioned they did not fall in battle. Plus your quote is for DA1.

Comment: @Blindly, after reviewing my answer I have made suitable edits.

Comment: @Oh wow traps, that's probably it, I just run through them cuz nothing really hurts..